# How can I tell whether a process is invoked via an agent or when logged in?

Tags: linux, bash

I am using a certain tool which executes via an agent on the Linux servers. We could execute it manually by logging into the Linux servers too.
I am trying to figure out (via Linux shell script) whether a user is logged in or whether the process is being invoked via the agent. Depending on this I want to execute different parts of the code.

Is there a variable in linux which helps ascertain this ?

Comment: Be more specific about what you mean by 'agent'?  Is your agent running under a different user account?  Can your 'agent' set an environment variable or something else that would allow you to detect this?  My point is, that you can almost certain set something that would allow you to see a difference, but depending on the exact details, there may be nothing to detect.  More details about what is being launched, and what the agent is, how it is launching things would probably let us give a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `pstree --show-parents` on the process ID. This will tell you what process started the program.

For example:

```
$ pstree -s 18445
systemd───sshd───sshd───sshd───bash

$ pstree -s 21797
systemd───nginx───nginx
```